# C++: too few arguments in function call

Tags: c++

i have problem in this code. when i call functions. compiler show this error:

"too few arguments in function call" 
............................................................

```
bool check_matrix(int x, int y){
    if (x<ROWS || y<COLUMNS)
        return true;
    return false;

    }

bool compute_duplicate(int x, int y, int array[], int array_length){
    for (int i=0; i< array_length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i]==compute_address(x,y))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
    }
////////////////////////////////////

for (int i=0; i<array_length; i++){
    if ((check_matrix(x,(y+1))==true) && compute_duplicate((x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false)) {
        array[i]= compute_address(x,(y+1));
        y++;
        d++;
        i++;
    }

    if ((check_matrix((x+1),y)==true) && compute_duplicate((x+1),y, array, array_length)==false)) {
        array[i]=compute_address((x+1),y);
        x++;
        d++;
        i++;
    }
    array_length=d;
}
```

Comment: Which function? Which line gives an error? Give the *actual* compiler error, not a small portion of it.

Comment: If you think you need to compare a boolean with `true`, then remember that the result of the comparison is also boolean, so you need to write `((check_matrix(x,(y+1))==true)==true)`.

Comment: More seriously, if you didn't render the code unreadable with all the unnecessary `==true/false`, and the extra parentheses around those comparisons, the problem would be quite obvious.

Comment: @Yuushi: it's clearly, functions are: check_matrix & compute_duplicate. can you see another function? i don't know why after a question asked, immediately vote down. :-(

Comment: @mahdimb: somebody didn't like this question for some reason (too simple? too many symbols? incomplete info?) and he voted it down; the rest is called "[bandwagon effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwagon_effect)" :) But your question is in fact not worse than the majority of questions on SO ==> so you get a "+1" from me - for Great Justice ;)

Comment: Maybe you could explain why _exactly_ you have troubling fixing the error.

Comment: @alex-shesterov: thank you, you are right, maybe really this is bandwagon effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function call has a misplaced bracket

```
compute_duplicate((x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false)
```

it should be

```
(compute_duplicate(x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false)
```

the same error exists in two places within your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
compute_duplicate((x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false))
```

I.e. you are trying to call `compute_duplicate` with *one* argument of type `bool`, which is the result of the **valid expression** `(x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false`. Note that comma is an operator in C/C++, so the effective result of the expression above is `array_length==false`.

What is probably meant is:

```
compute_duplicate(x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false
```

Answer (score 2):

`compute_duplicate((x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false))` is calling `compute_duplicate` on the expression `(x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false)`, which is a single boolean value that is `true` if and only if `(x,(y+1), array, array_length)` is `false`. This is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

An extra pair of braces here:

```
compute_duplicate((x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false)
```

Makes the compiler think you pass a single bool as argument. Loose them and error should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`compute_duplicate((x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false)` is calling `compute_duplicate` with one argument, the result of `(x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false`.

Did you mean `(compute_duplicate(x,(y+1), array, array_length)==false)` ?

(Just a slightly different arrangement of `()`s but a very different piece of C++.